# Automatically change font size for a stretched image in a picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I have a `PictureBox` that its size is fixed to 480x360 pixels. I write some text using `DrawString` on the image in the picturebox. If size of the image that user is selecting for the picturebox is already 480x360, it is no problem!

Problems starts when user is adding an image with smaller or greated size of default 480x360 pixels. In this case the default fonr size that I am writing strings on the images will be either too big or too small.

Is there a way to select font size depending on the images width and height? The pictures I am using in the program mostly are 4:3 ratio.

At the moment I am using the code below...it is somehow working but it is not a good way for doing so. What can be a smarter way?!

```
        private int GetProperFontSize()
    {
        var width = _bitmap.Width;

        if(width > 480 && width <= 680)
        {
            return 20;
        }

        if (width > 680 && width <= 800)
        {
            return 24;
        }

        if (width > 800 && width <= 1024)
        {
            return 32;
        }

        if (width > 1024 && width <= 1600)
        {
            return 44;
        }

        if (width > 1600 && width <= 2048)
        {
            return 50;
        }

        if (width > 2048 && width <= 2560)
        {
            return 66;
        }

        if (width > 2560 && width <= 6000)
        {
            return 80;
        }

        return 16;
    }
```

Comment: yes. simply do what I said below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can prohibit the user from using images of a smaller size...with the larger size simply scale it to the constrained width. you can also try things like setting a background color of black, centering the image, and then placing a white band at the bottom for the text like a polaroid...